# HTML to MS Word doc with total number of pages

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a Word document using HTML.

Thanks to a number of examples I have been able to acheive this. However, I can't seem to place the total number of pages in text at the top of the first page in the document.

I am trying to add, "This document contains "PAGENUM" of pages in the first line of text, but when the document is created, the "PAGENUM" is blank (other than in the footer that I also would like to keep).

Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible or am I just getting it completely wrong?

My code (Thanks to another user Vahid) is as follows,

```
<html
xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'       xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word'
xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>

<!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<w:WordDocument>
<w:View>Print</w:View>
<w:Zoom>100</w:Zoom>
</w:WordDocument>
</xml><![endif]-->
<style>
<!-- /* Style Definitions */
p.MsoHeader, li.MsoHeader, div.MsoHeader{
margin:0in;
margin-top:.0001pt;
mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in;
}
p.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, div.MsoFooter{
margin:0in 0in 1in 0in;
margin-bottom:.0001pt;
mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in;
}
.footer {
font-size: 9pt;
}
@page Section1{
size:8.5in 11.0in;
margin:0.5in 0.5in 0.5in 0.5in;
mso-header-margin:0.5in;
mso-header:h1;
mso-footer:f1;
mso-footer-margin:0.5in;
mso-paper-source:0;
}
div.Section1{
page:Section1;
}
table#hrdftrtbl{
margin:0in 0in 0in 9in;
} 
-->
</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen,print">
body {
font-family: "Calibri", "Verdana","HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-size:12pt;
}
pageBreak {
clear:all;
page-break-before:always;
mso-special-character:line-break;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style='tab-interval:.5in'>
<div class="Section1">

 This document contains <span style='mso-field-code: NUMPAGES '></span> pages.

 MORE CONTENT

<table id='hrdftrtbl' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style='mso-element:header' id="h1" >
                <p class="MsoHeader">
                    <table border="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>

                                YOUR_HEADER IMAGE/TEXT

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </p>
           </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div style='mso-element:footer' id="f1">
            <p class="MsoFooter">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0"      cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" class="footer">
                        YOUR_FOOTER_TEXT
                            <g:message code="offer.letter.page.label"/>           <span style='mso-field-code: PAGE '></span> of <span style='mso-field-code: NUMPAGES '></span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </p>
        </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to do it in Word and clean a bit the code it generates, you get something like this:

```
            ...
<div class="Section1">

 This document contains
 <!--[if supportFields]>
  <span>
   <span style='mso-element:field-begin'></span>
   <span style='mso-spacerun:yes'> </span>
   NUMPAGES
   <span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>  </span>
   \* MERGEFORMAT <span style='mso-element:field-separator'></span>
  </span>
 <![endif]-->
 <span style='mso-no-proof:yes'>X</span>
 <!--[if supportFields]>
  <span>
   <span style='mso-element:field-end'></span>
  </span>
 <![endif]--> pages.

 MORE CONTENT
        ...
```

Please note that when you open the Word document, you have to "Update field" to see the correct number of pages. Otherwise it will display the "mso-no-proof" value (here "X").

Comment: Thank you for the guidance and example. Unfortunately what I am trying to acheive is to create all the content by using HTML forms and once complete, generate the completed word document. I was hoping that the PAGENUM generated in the footer could somehow be duplicated at the top of the document.

Comment: Is there a way to update automatically as the document opens? - that would work a treat

Comment: Well, you can select all with CTRL+A and press F9 to update all the fields of the document. Also, if you print out the document, fields will be automatically updated (you can verify with print preview). Does it fit with what you need? Or do you wish to keep your document as a Word file?

Comment: Thank you for the clarity, this is brilliant. Ideally I would of liked to see the number of pages when I opened the document, but this also updates when saving the document as a PDF. Flot, you're a legend - Thank you

Comment: I'm glad that it helped :) One more thing: I don't know a way to auto-refresh via HTML only, but maybe you can update the tags of your post ? Maybe someone else will be able to do something like this in VBA...?